# Facebook IOS SDK 4.8.0 not returning to the app after Login

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

I have integrated Facebook Login to my iOS app which was working fine till yesterday. And today, I found out that it is not returning to the my app. I checked with Facebook Debugging where it prints as success for Login Completion and Permission Acceptance. But when everything is completed, it does not return to my app.

To test if this is issue from Facebook being not responding properly, I downloaded an app from AppStore and tested Facebook Login inside that app, it works perfect. I don't know what the hell is going on in my app.

Comment: Did you properly register the fb{YOUR_APP_ID} URL scheme in your app's Info.plist?

Comment: I have the same problem with my App, all of a sudden it stopped redirecting back to my App.

Answer (score 3):

In Login Action Add these lines so that Facebook will be opened in popup

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
login.loginBehavior=FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;  // it open inside the app using popup menu
```

Comment: It worked fine, but is there any way I can have it with the browser option?

Comment: Yes it works fine with the browser option also. Please check once again .

Comment: Nope, browser is not redirecting to App after login/authorization. That's was the main problem is. Still, you solution works fine.

Comment: ok Fine. Even i got same issue with my previous app but now when i am creating new Fbapp means its returning to app.

Comment: Experiencing the same problem. Web pops-up for login and permission but after it close, the Login button remains the same. Successful login isn't returned to the application.

Comment: @AqibBangash Here it is displaying results when opened in pop up and navigating to the application